# Show there is no derivative at $(0,0)$ for graph.

Tags: calculus

I have an equation defined in $x$ and $y$

$$2(x^2+y^2)^2 = 25(x^2-y^2)$$
And I am required to show that the derivative does not exist at $(x,y) =(0,0)$. How do I go about doing so?

So what I did thus far is differentiate the function implicitly and get the result

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{dy}{dx}\end{pmatrix} = \frac{x(25x-4x^2-4y)}{y(25+4x^2+4y^2)}$$

And I kinda know that $ \frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=0$ is $\frac{0}{0}$.
How do I argue, from here that the derivative does not exist?

Comment: Syntax error, this is not a function but an equation. Do you want a 2 variable function ($(x,y)\mapsto$ LHS-RHS) or an expression  like $y(x)$, as  you started?

Comment: Noted and changed. Is this the right phrasing? Regarding your question, can I ask for an expression like $y(x)$? I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0, y \rightarrow 0}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{dy}{dx}\end{pmatrix}$$ doesn't exist, you can choose two paths that will give two different limits (say $x=y$ and $x=y^2$).